# Application with physical root failed to start process with commandline 'dotnet .\AppName.dll', ErrorCode = '0x80004005 : 80008083

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, iis-7, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012

I have visual studio 2015 installed on my machine along with .NET core SDK 1.0.1 (3133). After creating a asp.net core application, when I host it on Win7 IIS/ WinServer 2008 R2 it work fine, but when I tried installing it on WinServer 2012 R2 IIS 8.5, I having following error

It was not possible to find any compatible framework version

The specified framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.0.1' was not found.

- Check application dependencies and target a framework version installed at:

  \
- Alternatively, install the framework version '1.0.1'.

Answer (score 6):

In this case we need to explicitly set the processPath in web.config to the exact location of dotnet.exe in Program files,

In my case, C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe

Comment: What about if u deploy to server ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was able to fix this issue by doing the following in web config

updating processPath
From "dotnet" to "C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe" and
arguments= from ".\app.dll" to "C:\System\publish\publish\app.dll" and
resetting IIS from cmd using command "IISReset" and the error is gone.